# Boostrap problem in the mobile responsive

Tags: html, css

I have an boostrap problem to align the button correctly, it cannot show me the view of position in change to the mobile view:

Below is my coding (effect my mobile view position):

```html
<div class="topnav" style="margin-right:5%;">
<span id="curTime" class='hide'>&nbsp;</span>
<div class="dropdown">
<a id="dropbtn" style="margin-right:20px;" href="#" onclick="setting()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Setting" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-metis-1 btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="?loc=user_designation">Tetapan Umum</a>
<a href="?loc=user">Pengurusan Pengguna</a>
</div>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="logout()" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Logout" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-metis-1 btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

Below is my output :

**(Normal view)**

[image: Output 1]

**(Mobile responsive view)**

[image: Output 2]

My expected result is like below the picture, the two buttons can align the same line:

[image: Output3]

Hope someone can guide me how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `dropdown` class if you don't want an actual dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the button in "ul" tag and "li" tag and you have to apply inline-block CSS.